# How to retrieve and display a single record with Vue and axios

Tags: vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, axios

I have a basic CRUD rails 5.2 API with a Story model. I am building a Vuejs front end to consume it. Currently, The index view at /stories successfully pulls in data from the server. I can also add stories to the database via NewStory.vue at stories/new. I am trying now to show a single story on a page at stories/:id. The api server currently shows the single result I need at v1/stories/:id.

here is what I have at services/Api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/v1`
  })
}
```

in StoriesService.js:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  fetchStories () {
    return Api().get('stories')
  },

  addStory (params) {
    return Api().post('stories', params)
  },

  getStory (params) {
    return Api().get('/stories/1')
  }
}
```

in ViewStory.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="stories">
    <h1>Story</h1>
    <div v-if="story" class="table-wrap">
      <div>
        <router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'NewStory' }" class="">Add 
Story</router-link>
      </div>
      <p>Title: {{story.attributes.title}}</p>
      <p>Overview: {{story.attributes.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
       The story with id:{{params}} does not exist <br><br>
       <!-- <router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'NewStory' }" 
class="add_story_link">Add Story</router-link> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import StoriesService from '@/services/StoriesService'
export default {
  name: 'story',
  data () {
    return {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getStory()
  },
  methods: {
    async getStory (params) {
      const response = await StoriesService.getStory(params)
      this.story = response.data
      console.log(this.story)
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

With the id of the record hard coded, in the Network tab, I see the request being made to the api and the correct record being retrieved.

[image]

However, if I change the getStory call to `return Api().get('/stories/', params)` I get a 304 response and can't retrieve data.

[image]

My question is how to get StoriesService.js to return localhost:3000/v1/stories/params.id, where params.id is the id of the story referenced in the url.

Comment: You don't pass in anything to your getStory when you call it from the mounted: `this.getStory()` so where do you get the id? Because using the router params `await StoriesService.getStory(this.$route.params)` and `getStory (params) {
    return Api().get(params);
  }` should work assuming a client side route `/stories/:id` which is pointing to your `ViewStory`

Comment: I mad your changes, but still no luck. in the view script:                              
    import StoriesService from '@/services/StoriesService'
    export default {
      name: 'story',
      data () {
        return {
          title: '',
          description: ''
         }
      },
      mounted () {
        this.getStory()
      },
      methods: {
        async getStory (params) {
          const response = await StoriesService.getStory(this.$route.params)
          this.story = response.data.data
          console.log(this.story)
        }
      }

Comment: How does your vue router config look like? Do you have a route like: `/stories/:id`?

Comment: I have this:  {
      path: '/stories/:id',
      name: 'ViewStory',
      component: ViewStory
    },

Comment: looking at the sever side log, i don't see the request being made at this point

Comment: actually axios only support query string parameters so it generates urls like `/stories?id=...` which is not recognized by your Rails routes, so you need to build the url in `getStory`:  `getStory (params) {
    return Api().get(\`/stories/${params.id}/\`)
  }`

Comment: Ok that was it. it seems to be working somewhat now.  but Vue still behaves strangely to me. so if I change the id in the url, the page responds that no story with that id was found, even though the network tab shows a 200 response with the correct data.  i.e. it is interpreting `v-if story` as false.  Btw, if you put your response in an answer, i can accept it.

Comment: actually if i change the i in the url, i get a 304 response, but the content does not display at all. just a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are not passing in any params to `getStory`, so you need to get them from the `this.$route.params`

```
async getStory () {
  const response = await StoriesService.getStory(this.$route.params)
  this.story = response.data
  console.log(this.story)
}
```

Beside that axios only supports query string parameters so if your url looks like /stories/someId then you need to build it yourself in `getStory`:

```
getStory (params) {
   return Api().get(`/stories/${params.id}`)
}
```

Additionally your data object is missing the `story` property:

```
data () {
  return {
    story: null,
    title: '',
    description: ''
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!